# split paragraphs just before a line which is start without any space

Tags: python, split

```
data = '''
eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
 device native, cast established.
  real fair, backup none
em 1, address 002, type ethernet
  device native, cast exit
eth 2, address 003, type ethernet
  device native, cast rescue0b0
  page device, native: action$
loopback 3, address 003, type ethernet
   device native
'''
```

i need to split like below.

```
eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
 device native, cast established.
 real fair, backup none


em 1, address 002, type ethernet
  device native, cast exit


eth 2, address 003, type ethernet
  device native, cast rescue0b0
  page device, native: action$


loopback 3, address 003, type ethernet
   device native
```

---

logic: eth, em, loopback .. all start without any space. and there could be multiple space before middle data. i need that logic

challenge: this is not mandatory to have a specific pattern at the end of each paragraph.

this is more specific question of
[split paragraphs with a line which is start without space and lookup the data perline in split data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223503/split-paragraphs-with-a-line-which-is-start-without-space-and-lookup-the-data-pe/47224900#47224900)

Comment: You just want to add an additional new line before each line (except the first one?) that starts with a non space character, right? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some regex here :

```
import re
pattern=r'^\S[\s\S]+?(?=^\S|\n{2,}|\Z)'
string_1='''eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
 device native, cast established.
  real fair, backup none
em 1, address 002, type ethernet
  device native, cast exit
eth 2, address 003, type ethernet
  device native, cast rescue0b0
  page device, native: action$
loopback 3, address 003, type ethernet
   device native'''

match=re.finditer(pattern,string_1,re.M)
for find in match:
    print(find.group())
```

Output:

```
eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
 device native, cast established.
  real fair, backup none

em 1, address 002, type ethernet
  device native, cast exit

eth 2, address 003, type ethernet
  device native, cast rescue0b0
  page device, native: action$

loopback 3, address 003, type ethernet
   device native
```

Comment: perfect thank you very much i got my output here. appreciate

Comment: Hi i m new to re. Appreciate you to please explain each expression so that I can learn further.

Comment: @NishantThakur , See the right hand side explanation here https://regex101.com/r/HOPcMD/1   :)

Comment: perfect... really appreciate your help. what is the use of \n{2,} here?

Comment: @NishantThakur \n match new line feed and {2,} Quantifier  Matches between 2 and unlimited times.

Comment: Sir, perfect. but I get a chance to try this script multiple times. its giving me accurate result without \n{2,} . my apology i am from network and dont have much understanding about python. can you please give me an working and non working example for this? will appreciate your help... :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the [**string.splitlines()**](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/splitlines.html) function to split
>   multi-line string at newlines.
>
> For splitting lines at other characters use [**string.split()**](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)
>   function.

```
data = '''
eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
 device native, cast established.
  real fair, backup none
em 1, address 002, type ethernet
  device native, cast exit
eth 2, address 003, type ethernet
  device native, cast rescue0b0
  page device, native: action$
loopback 3, address 003, type ethernet
   device native
'''

splittedLines = data.splitlines()

for word in splittedLines:
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
 device native, cast established.
  real fair, backup none

em 1, address 002, type ethernet
  device native, cast exit

eth 2, address 003, type ethernet
  device native, cast rescue0b0
  page device, native: action$

loopback 3, address 003, type ethernet
   device native
```

Comment: print("1" + word)

output========
1
1eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
1 device native, cast established.
1  real fair, backup none


what i need=======
1
1eth 0, address 001, type ethernet
 device native, cast established.
  real fair, backup none
1em 1, address 002, type ethernet

Comment: @NishantThakur could you elaborate what you are trying to do?